# Помогите найти ошибку в игре "Найди Клад" js

Tags: javascript

```js
//получаем рандомное число 
var getRandomNumber = function (size) {
 return Math.floor(Math.random() * size);
};
//получаем растояние от клада до клика
var getDistance = function (event, target) {
 var diffX = event.offsetX - target.x;
 var diffY = event.offsetY - target.y;
 return Math.sqrt((diffX * diffX) + (diffY * diffY));
};
//возвращаем подсказку
var getDistanceHint = function (distance) {
 if (distance < 10) {
  return "Обожжешься!";
 } else if (distance < 20) {
  return "Очень горячо!";
 } else if (distance < 40) {
  return "Горячо";
 } else if (distance < 80) {
  return "Тепло";
 } else if (disntace < 160) {
  return "Холодно";
 } else if (disntace < 320) {
  return "Очень холодно!";
 } else {
  return "Замерзнешь!";
 }
};
//переменные
var clicks = 0;
var width = 400;
var height = 400;
//рандомное расположение клада
var target = {
 x: getRandomNumber(width),
 y: getRandomNumber(height)
};
//эвент клика 
$("map").click(function (event) {
 clicks++;
 //собираем все вместе
    var distance = getDistance(event, target);
    var distanceHint = getDistanceHint(distance);
    $("#distance").text(distanceHint);
//проверка на выигрыш
if (distance < 8) {
 alert("Клад найден! Сделанно кликов: " + clicks);
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="map" width=400 height=400 src="https://nostarch.com/images/treasuremap.png">

<p id="distance"></p>
```

Суть игры в том, что бы найти сокровище, которое при каждом запуске появляется в рандомном месте на картике #map. Искать нужно с помощью всплывающих подсказок(внутри тега "p") по типу "горячо" "холодно". Проблема в том, что когда я нажимаю на карту, текста с подсказками не выводиться и ничего не происходит. Вот пример работающей версии(я пытаюсь сделать такую же игру сам) но не понимаю, что отличается в моей версии от работающей.

```js
// Get a random number from 0 to size
    var getRandomNumber = function (size) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * size);
    };

    // Calculate distance between click event and target
    var getDistance = function (event, target) {
      var diffX = event.offsetX - target.x;
      var diffY = event.offsetY - target.y;
      return Math.sqrt((diffX * diffX) + (diffY * diffY));
    };

    // Get a string representing the distance
    var getDistanceHint = function (distance) {
      if (distance < 10) {
        return "Boiling hot!";
      } else if (distance < 20) {
        return "Really hot";
      } else if (distance < 40) {
        return "Hot";
      } else if (distance < 80) {
        return "Warm";
      } else if (distance < 160) {
        return "Cold";
      } else if (distance < 320) {
        return "Really cold";
      } else {
        return "Freezing!";
      }
    };

    // Set up our variables
    var width = 400;
    var height = 400;
    var clicks = 0;

    // Create a random target location
    var target = {
      x: getRandomNumber(width),
      y: getRandomNumber(height)
    };

    // Add a click handler to the img element
    $("#map").click(function (event) {
      clicks++;

      // Get distance between click event and target
      var distance = getDistance(event, target);
      // Convert distance to a hint
      var distanceHint = getDistanceHint(distance);

      // Update the #distance element with the new hint
      $("#distance").text(distanceHint);

      // If the click was close enough, tell them they won
      if (distance < 8) {
        alert("Found the treasure in " + clicks + " clicks!");
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="map" width=400 height=400 src="http://nostarch.com/images/treasuremap.png">
 <p id="distance"></p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут 3 ошибки, ничего не работает потому что Вы навешиваете клик на элемент по идентификатору но `#` забыли, еще 2 опечатки в названии переменной `distance` внутри проверки дистанции.

```js
//получаем рандомное число 
var getRandomNumber = function(size) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * size);
};
//получаем растояние от клада до клика
var getDistance = function(event, target) {
  var diffX = event.offsetX - target.x;
  var diffY = event.offsetY - target.y;
  return Math.sqrt((diffX * diffX) + (diffY * diffY));
};
//возвращаем подсказку
var getDistanceHint = function(distance) {
  if (distance < 10) {
    return "Обожжешься!";
  } else if (distance < 20) {
    return "Очень горячо!";
  } else if (distance < 40) {
    return "Горячо";
  } else if (distance < 80) {
    return "Тепло";
  } else if (distance < 160) {
    return "Холодно";
  } else if (distance < 320) {
    return "Очень холодно!";
  } else {
    return "Замерзнешь!";
  }
};
//переменные
var clicks = 0;
var width = 400;
var height = 400;
//рандомное расположение клада
var target = {
  x: getRandomNumber(width),
  y: getRandomNumber(height)
};
//эвент клика 
$("#map").click(function(event) {
  clicks++;
  //собираем все вместе
  var distance = getDistance(event, target);
  var distanceHint = getDistanceHint(distance);
  $("#distance").text(distanceHint);
  //проверка на выигрыш
  if (distance < 8) {
    alert("Клад найден! Сделанно кликов: " + clicks);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="map" width=400 height=400 draggable="false" src="https://nostarch.com/images/treasuremap.png">
<p id="distance"></p>
```

---

UPD: предлагаю определять дистанцию не через `if` + добавил Вам `"heatmap"` для отладки =)

```js
var names = ["Обожжешься","Очень горячо","Горячо","Тепло","Холодно","Очень холодно","Замерзнешь"]
var heat = ["red", "#f66", "yellow", "green", "#90f", "cyan", "blue"];
var clicks = 0;
var width = 400;
var height = 400;

var target = {
  x: Math.random() * width,
  y: Math.random() * height
};

$("#map").click(function(event) {
  clicks++;
  var distance = getDistance(event.offsetX, event.offsetY, target);
  $("#distance").text(names[getIndexByDistance(distance)]);
  if (distance < 8) 
    alert("Клад найден! Сделанно кликов: " + clicks);
});

var ctx = heatmap.getContext('2d');
for (var y = 0; y < height; y++)
  for (var x = 0; x < width; x++)
    drawHeatMap(x,y)

function drawHeatMap(x,y){
  var distance = getDistance(x, y);
  ctx.fillStyle = heat[getIndexByDistance(distance)]
  ctx.fillRect(x,y,1,1)
}

function getDistance(x, y) {
  var dX = x - target.x;
  var dY = y - target.y;
  return Math.sqrt(dX * dX + dY * dY);
}

function getIndexByDistance(distance){
  return Math.floor(Math.log2(distance/10))
}
```

```css
img, canvas {
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:0;
}
body {
  margin:0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="distance"></span>
<img id="map" width=400 height=400 draggable="false" src="https://nostarch.com/images/treasuremap.png">
<canvas id="heatmap" width=400 height=400 style="pointer-events:none;opacity:0.3"></canvas>
```